# API Gateway changing url invoke and api key

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-api-gateway

The invoke url and api key of of an api that I implemented in the gateway api changed without me asking. I don't want them to keep changing all the time. I didn't find an answer to my problem in the aws documentation. Maybe the problem is usage plan?

Here the serveless.yml

```
# serverless.yml
service: extrator
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  stackName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
  apiKeys:
    - name:  ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
      usagePlan:
        name:  ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
        quota:
          limit: 50000
          period: DAY
        throttle:
          burstLimit: 1000
          rateLimit: 500
  stackPolicy:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action: Update:*
      Principal: "*"
      Resource: "*"
  environment:
    FEED_BUCKET_NAME: !Ref Bucket
    ECS_CLUSTER: !GetAtt FargateECSCluster.Arn
    ECS_TASK_ARN: !Ref FargateECSTaskDefinition
    ECS_SUBNET: !Ref FargateSubnet
    ECS_SEC_GROUP: !Ref FargateSG
    CONTAINER_NAME: !Ref "AWS::StackName"

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:PutObject"
      Resource: !Sub
        - "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*"
        - BucketName: !Ref "AWS::StackName"

    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - ecs:RunTask
      Resource:
        - !Ref FargateECSTaskDefinition
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - iam:PassRole
      Resource:
        - !GetAtt FargateExecutionRole.Arn
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - iam:PassRole
      Resource:
        - !GetAtt FargateTaskRole.Arn

functions:
  lambda:
    handler: lambda_function.launch_fargate
    runtime: ${self:provider.runtime}
    events:
      - http:
          path: extract
          method: get
          integration: lambda
          private: true

resources:
  - AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
    Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
  - ${file(./resources.yml)}
```

Comment: The invoke url cannot change unless you destroy (and re-create) the api gateway.

Comment: well, so i dont know whats happened. I have save the request in postman and invoke url and api key are different than i see in aws